# Listing order on App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, itunes-store

In App Store app, if I search for a word.  What does the returned listing order of apps base on?  Let's say, it returned app1, app2, app3, ..., app10.  What was the listing order based upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sorted by relevance by default, but you can change it in the upper right corner, by clicking relevance. The option are then

- Relevance
- Most popular
- Release date
- Customer rating

[image]